Power Over Ethernet (POE) switch to run multiple cameras on a single Ethernet cable?
I just installed a POE (Power Over Ethernet) camera system in my home and shop (same building). All of the cameras are on the soffits, so all of the Ethernet cables go through the attic, and the installation looks very neat. My office is on the bottom floor of the 2-story house, so it did take me forever to run 12 Ethernet cables from the attic to the bottom floor, as I did not want any exposed cables to the outside, but also, due to the design of my house, running these 12 cables through the wall cavities would have taken more time than I had.
Question: did I just waste 3 days running those 12 cables + also waste 500' of extra cable, running individual Ethernet cables from each camera to the server in the first floor? Could I have put a POE switch in the attic and then run just one Ethernet cable from the attic to the server?

I meant my question below about routing the cables to be here, not there.  So, you have I guess vinyl siding with a big vertical corner piece with enough space inside for 12 ethernet cables?  Handy!  And clever to use it.  My siding is mitered at the corners so I couldn't do that.

hopefully you didn't use cca cable.

@FreshCodemonger I just checked the box. It says 100% certified fresh copper. I hope it's true

You could have installed a ~16 port POE ethernet switch up in the attic, which would have taken one cable as an "uplink" to the office, and then 12 cables fanning out to the cameras, with three more spare ports.   24 ports is another common size, giving more room for expansion.
Downside - attics are horrible places for any computer gear to operate.  They get both hot and cold, dusty, damp and potentially have rodents/birds.
POE switches tend to run hotter than regular switches too, so cooling is more important.  If the fans fail, you might not even notice.
Additionally you need to get power up to the switch in the attic, and that would be a mains-voltage AC socket.  Depending on your jurisdiction, this may require an electrician, especially if this is a business or a rental rather than your own home.
I think you did the right thing running all 12 ethernet cables down to the core switching area in the office.  This gives you added flexibility in the future, and your POE switch will have LEDs showing clearly if something isn't working.
Also, you can put this whole rack/stack on a decent UPS and have it continue to run in a power-outage.
You are correct - Cabling is indeed a faff, but done right it will be serviceable for decades and can work with multiple generations of camera.  Wireless cameras clutter the spectrum continuously, and noone's invented a practical wireless power transmission standard (Zeus excepted)

You could have put a poe switch in an upstairs closet to avoid the temperature problems. That's what I would have done, at least initially. But I agree with this answer, you'll have a better time keeping it running well by having it centralized in the basement. Enjoy.

You don't need to run AC power to the roof switch: there's POE-powered switches that pass through. You'd likely run POE++ to power a number of POE cameras.

@user71659 true they do exist, but I've never seen one that could run more than one or two downstream ports, due to power budgets.   Normal POE is ~15 watts, so if the attic switch used 5, that would only leave 10W  to run other downstream devices.     My cameras use between 5 and 12W depending on whether IR is on, so OP's 12 cameras would need 60W minimum.   This is beyond normal POE, though as you note, there do exist higher power POE standards (and prices !)

@Criggie An Ubiqiuti Flex switch will source 46 W over 4 PoE+ ports with PoE++ inputs. This will fully power 4 Ubiquiti G5 Pro cameras, rated at 10 W each. Or with G5 Flex (4 W), an Ultra with 7 PoE+ outputs, 42 W budget on PoE++ input. All of these pieces are less than $120. A PoE++ injector is $30.

@user71659 Last time I looked, 4 is less than 12.   So OP would need three switches in the roof and another POE++ switch downstairs, with three drop cables minimum.   Seems overly-complex.  I stand by my statement that doing cabling is a faff but ultimately  leads to a cleaner better solution.   Could you post your own answer to OP's original question and we'll clean up this chat.

Yes. One cable would do fine.
Note that PoE Router is not really a relevant term; generally PoE is supplied by either injectors or switches. Routers refer to routing, which is not relevant when discussing PoE (or Ethernet in general).
As you have 12 cameras, you would likely require gigabit Ethernet on the link, but most modern equipment supports that just fine.

Makes sense, thank you. Maybe it was not a bad idea to run the 12 cables anyway, as the attic ranges in temperature from -20C in the winter to 65C in the summer, so perhaps having an Ethernet switch up there would not have worked after all.

65°C is certainly at the extreme upper end of what such devices are rated for. You're looking at industrial switches typically priced at 10x the normal office switches for that temperature. This switch covers -40°C to +60°C, and will set you back ~1700€.

I would put as much of the electronics as possible in a human-conditioned space. Even the basement is probably a better bet than the attic.

Curious, how did you get 12 cables through the framing between the 1st and second floors?  Did you remove a large piece of wall in order to work freely and directly on that?

@jay613 I wanted to avoid opening up indoor walls, so I went soffits - attic - corner soffit - under corner trim - under bottom of siding - drill wall to first floor

Mikrotik claims operating temps up to 70ºC.

Some years ago I ran cables from 6 PTZ cameras on the outside edges of my house to a POE switch, and one cable from the switch to the computer, so yes, that works and saves a lot of cabling.
One gotcha was that I found the cameras could need up to 40 watts each, but the 6-port switches I had could only support a max of 120 total watts (20 watts per port max), so I ended up chaining two switches with one more cable and put 3 cameras on each switch, which works fine, but be sure you take those kinds of power limitations into account before finalizing your hardware configuration.
